# In R remove all characters in string that is substring of other character

Tags: r, grepl

This is a simple toy example. I would like to only keep the shortest sub-string. AB we keep and ABC can be excluded. BD and ADB we keep because there is no langer character that also has this pattern.

```
have <- c('AB', 'BD', 'ADB', 'ABC')
want <- c('AB', 'BD', 'ADB')
```

grepl is very useful here but I'm not sure how to make it computationally efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R approach:

```
have <- c('AB', 'BD', 'ADB', 'ABC')
keep <- sapply(have, function(x) grepl(paste0(have[!have %in% x], collapse="|"), x))
want <- have[!keep]
want

[1] "AB"  "BD"  "ADB"
```

The idea here is, for each entry in your input vector, to build a regex alternation consisting of the *remaining* terms.  So, when `sapply` reaches the final value `ABC`, we form the following regex alternation:

```
AB|BD|ABD
```

Then, we use `grepl` to see if we can find any entry which is a substring of `ABC`.  In this case, we can, using `AB`, so then we mark as true.  Finally, we subset the input vector using this boolean vector.

Comment: Tim, is it possible to use regex lookahead in this scenario?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I thought of iterating through each string and look if the pattern exists in the other strings in the vector using lookahead.